# handling the table pagination when refreshing remote data programmatically

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am trying to use the same scenario(https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/383) with my own API end point, In my response result I don't have totalCount and page values. Without them my table pagination says `NaN-NaN of undefined`

I am able to handle the totalCount by result.length, With this being handled I can see pagination as `NaN-NaN of 38`(38 is count of array items) but I am unable to proceed to nextpage.
Here is my code:

```
data={query =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dev/getcustomerinstructors', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.state.id_token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "refresh_token": this.state.refresh_token,
            "customer_id": this.state.customer_id,
        })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result); //array of objects
        resolve({
          data: result,
          // page: 0, **//how to address this** 
          totalCount: result.length,
        })
      });
  })
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

`const page =  (query.page + 1);` and updating the page value `page: page - 1` after response did the trick.

```
data={query =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getcustomerinstructors';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.state.id_token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "refresh_token": this.state.refresh_token,
            "customer_id": this.state.customer_id,
            "role": this.state.role
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      var res = result.slice(query.page * query.pageSize, (query.page * query.pageSize) + query.pageSize);
      resolve({
        data: res,
        page: query.page,
        totalCount: result.length,
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: But I still have an issue, Even though I can navigate to next page the table data is not being updated.

Comment: Now table data is getting updated, Edited the above code to fix that.